# How to create an antnest outworld

Tags: containment, insects, invertebrates

I'm an antkeeper and was wondering if someone knows how to go about doing a proper antnest outworld. I did make some outworlds with sand to prevent my colony from digging to deep, but I was wondering if I should add some cleaner insects like springtails to clean up their waste from those spots that are harder to clean/reach. My current main colony is a *Messor Barbarus* and I have also learned a lot about ants just by keeping them.

Now I was wondering since I made a big anttank basically with clay soil from a pet store (Fress Napf) and I don't know if I should throw in some cleaner insects or where to get them. I ask because I cannot monitor the inside of their nest and even though I barely have to clean often them, it would make me feel much better knowing that they had some extra help.

Comment: Welcome to Pets! Please take the [tour], it only takes a minute. Unfortunately it's very hard to understand your question. Do you mean "outside" with "outworld"? Is the nest surrounded by a container or do you just dig a hole and fill it with special soil? You seem to speak German (and you're not the only one on this site), so maybe [edit] your question and write down your thoughts in German. One of us will translate it for you.

Comment: I am happy to help with translation issues :) but I have no knowledge avout ants ^^ Ich helfe gerne beim Übersetzen, hab aber keine Ahnung von Ameisen ;)

Comment: I read about speingtails, that they are food for ants. Do you plan to add the springtails as living food and cleaner?

Comment: To make things clear, I do speak German, however are my English and German skill on a quite decent level. For the question about the outworld, it's a term that antkeepers use to call the part of the nest that has some soil (sand, dirt, clay, etc.) and sometimes plants. So it's basically a tank with soil for the ants. No ants don't eat springtails, although some trap jaw ants may farm them as a food source but most ants don't. But yeah I am curious if there would be a good choice for this or ideas on how to handle this.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this special term!